# loop through elements and set CSS styling at same time

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I want to loop through elements with a class and then loop the individual element and gradually decrease the "left" css property.

```js
let move = document.getElementsByClassName("move");
for (var i = 0; i < move.length; i++) {
  const left = move[i].getBoundingClientRect().left;
  const elementId = move[i].id;
  for (let j = left; j > -20; j--) {
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.left = j + "%";
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 20));
  }
}
```

However, I'm using "await" to delay so that it moves slowly and doesn't zip across the screen. I want it so that all the elements have their CSS left property decrease at the **same** time. But instead, because of the await, the first element increases its left property and when its left property reaches the end, only then the next element goes. Please advise

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [mcve] here to allow the community to better understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

While I think it would be better to use pure CSS transitions/animations for this, you could use a while loop to iterate over the elements with the `move` class, subtracting 1% from their left value until they are completely off screen (right <= 0).

```
const start = async () => {
  const move = document.getElementsByClassName("move");

  const canMoveLeft = () => {
    const move = document.getElementsByClassName("move");
    for (let i = 0; i < move.length; i++) {
      if (move[i].getBoundingClientRect().right > 0) return true;
    }
    return false;
  };
  
  while (canMoveLeft()) {
    for (let i = 0; i < move.length; i++) {
      const { left, right } = move[i].getBoundingClientRect();
      if (right > 0) {
        const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        const leftVal = `${Math.round((left / windowWidth) * 100) - 1}%`;
        document.getElementById(move[i].id).style.left = leftVal;
      }
    }

    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 20));
  }
};
```

[image: Edit loop-through-elements-and-set-css-styling-at-same-time]

Comment: then left is not defined

Comment: @Vivaan4 Oh, you're right, I see that now. Where are you wanting to transition/animate from, or rather, how many steps do you want/need it to take? Do you have a running example for this code you are working with, or can you create one for us to examine? Codesandbox is handy for this.

Comment: So all the elements with the class "move" have their own ID as well, with their starting left property. so I want the loop to make all the elements with move class to start from their predefined values of left in CSS and go to -20% (leaving at the same time, but not arriving at the same time, for example if a element has 80% left and anotherhas 90%, the 80% should reach a bit faster. In the example I showed above, the problem was that only when 1 of the element reached -20%, only then the second would go, then when the 2nd one reached onlythen the 3rd on went and so on)

Comment: @Vivaan4 I see, so wherever they are mounted and start from, move left 1%/20ms until they all hit -20% left? Do you have something basic running already that we can start from and play with?

Comment: Yes @Drew Reese. But the code I wrote above makes it so when the first element reached -20% only then does the 2nd one start moving. So I want to find out how to do it.

Comment: Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-sea-sgsrn

Comment: @Vivaan4 Please check updated answer that includes forked codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want to animate `left` property of elements with class "move".

If that's the case you can do:

1st:

add [transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) property in `move` class

```
.move {
 transition: left 2s;
}
```

2nd:

```
let move = document.getElementsByClassName("move");
for(let item of move) {
 item.style.left = "-20%";
}
```